# XSLT to add an element hierarchy tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having to Convert XML to another XML by replacing xml element with element start tag based on condition. Input may have multiple level element and level element may have another level as child or siblings.

Below is my input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
  <Collection>
    <Primary>
      <PrimaryName>1238</PrimaryName>
      <Content>1</Content>
      <Modifier>81</Modifier>
    </Primary>
  </Collection>
  <CModifier>55</CModifier>
  <LEVEL>BEGIN</LEVEL>
  <Collection>
    <Primary>
      <PrimaryName>1023</PrimaryName>
      <Content>1</Content>
      <Modifier>81</Modifier>
    </Primary>
  </Collection>
  <CModifier>99</CModifier>
  <LEVEL>BEGIN</LEVEL>
  <LEVEL>BEGIN</LEVEL>
  <Collection>
    <Primary>
      <PrimaryName>5754</PrimaryName>
      <Content>Testing%</Content>
      <Modifier>11</Modifier>
    </Primary>
  </Collection>
  <LEVEL>END</LEVEL>
  <LEVEL>END</LEVEL>
  <LEVEL>END</LEVEL>
</Data>
```

And I'm trying to convert this into following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
  <Collection>
    <Primary>
      <PrimaryName>1238</PrimaryName>
      <Content>1</Content>
      <Modifier>81</Modifier>
    </Primary>
  </Collection>
  <CModifier>55</CModifier>
  <LEVEL>
  <Collection>
    <Primary>
      <PrimaryName>1023</PrimaryName>
      <Content>1</Content>
      <Modifier>81</Modifier>
    </Primary>
  </Collection>
  <CModifier>99</CModifier>
  <LEVEL>
  <LEVEL>
  <Collection>
    <Primary>
      <PrimaryName>5754</PrimaryName>
      <Content>Testing%</Content>
      <Modifier>11</Modifier>
    </Primary>
  </Collection>
  </LEVEL>
  </LEVEL>
  </LEVEL>
</Data>
```

I tried with following XSLT but looks like I cant just add start tag or end tag based on condition.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="LEVEL">
        <xsl:if test="LEVEL='BEGIN'">
            <level>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="LEVEL='END'">
            </level>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a difficult problem. Your attempt cannot succeed because an XSLT stylesheet must also be a well-formed XML document.

The following stylesheet will work on the given example. Hopefully all your input documents will satisfy the assumption being made here.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="node-by-level" match="node()" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::LEVEL[.='BEGIN'][1])" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="LEVEL[.='BEGIN'][1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LEVEL[.='BEGIN']">
    <LEVEL>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('node-by-level', generate-id())"/>
    </LEVEL>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LEVEL[.='END']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

To cope with the added complexity in your edited question, I would do the transformation in two passes:

**XSLT 1.0 (+EXSLT node-set function)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="elem-by-level" match="*" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::BEGIN[@level=current()/@level - 1][1])" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <!-- first pass, using sibling recursion -->
    <xsl:variable name="first-pass">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]" mode="first-pass"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($first-pass)/*[@level=0]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- first pass templates -->

<xsl:template match="*" mode="first-pass">
    <xsl:param name="level" select="0"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="level">
            <xsl:value-of select="$level"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="first-pass">
        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LEVEL[.='BEGIN']" mode="first-pass">
    <xsl:param name="level" select="0"/>
    <BEGIN level="{$level}"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="first-pass">
        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LEVEL[.='END']" mode="first-pass">
    <xsl:param name="level" select="0"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="first-pass">
        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level - 1"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>  
</xsl:template>

<!-- output templates -->

<xsl:template match="BEGIN">
    <LEVEL>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('elem-by-level', generate-id())"/>
    </LEVEL>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@level"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Testing with the following input example:

**XML**

```
<Data>
    <Item name="0A"/>
    <Item name="0B"/>
    <LEVEL>BEGIN</LEVEL>
    <Item name="1A"/>
    <LEVEL>BEGIN</LEVEL>
    <LEVEL>BEGIN</LEVEL>
    <Item name="3A"/>
    <LEVEL>END</LEVEL>
    <Item name="2A"/>
    <LEVEL>END</LEVEL>
    <Item name="1B"/>
    <LEVEL>END</LEVEL>
    <Item name="0C"/>
    <LEVEL>BEGIN</LEVEL>
    <Item name="1C"/>
    <LEVEL>END</LEVEL>
    <Item name="0D"/>
</Data>
```

produces:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Data>
  <Item name="0A" />
  <Item name="0B" />
  <LEVEL>
    <Item name="1A" />
    <LEVEL>
      <LEVEL>
        <Item name="3A" />
      </LEVEL>
      <Item name="2A" />
    </LEVEL>
    <Item name="1B" />
  </LEVEL>
  <Item name="0C" />
  <LEVEL>
    <Item name="1C" />
  </LEVEL>
  <Item name="0D" />
</Data>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ38Zr

Comment: @Jags Can you be more specific? It works fine in my testing and here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYiC

Comment: Then they must be using a non-conforming processor.

Comment: I tried your solution at below url and found it not to be working.
http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/#.XMUcoJNKjGJ but later I tried https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ and it seems to be working for this case, but for few other use case when I had more level element as sibling and few more level element as child of another level element, this does not seems to work as expected. like you said "Hopefully all your input documents will satisfy the assumption being made here." I think I have few more variations of input data and to few of them it's not working.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will try to understand your solution  and see how I can modify that. This will help me understand XSLT better.

Comment: Well, I can only answer the questions that are asked. If you have more examples or - preferably - a **rule** governing the structure of your input, you can add them to your question, or ask a new one.

Comment: Thanks, Edited Input XML and also do you mind elaborating your solution. Trying to understand your solution.

Comment: I will not address your edited example until you specify the rules. My answer above assumes all `Collection`s belong to a `LEVEL`. Now you have a `Collection` that is above the top `LEVEL` in hierarchy - but it is not clear (a) whether such `Collection` can appear anywhere in the XML and (b) whether there  can be more that one top `LEVEL `. --- As for elaborating: it's a rather simple idea: every node "learns" the unique id of its nearest preceding `<LEVEL>BEGIN</LEVEL>` sibling; when this sibling is processed, it gathers all its nodes by calling them by its unique id.

Comment: a. Yes, Such collection can appear anywhere in XML. b. There can be more than one top level.

Comment: See the addition to my post.

Comment: Thanks much and truly appreciate your response.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that a much better solution would be to change the input XML schema. This is a classic case of a fool throwing a stone into a well which a hundred wise men struggle to pull out.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 solution using the technique of "sibling recursion":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="3.0" xmlns:f="http://local/"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    expand-text="yes">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:function name="f:depth" as="xs:integer">
        <xsl:param name="n" as="element()"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="count($n/preceding-sibling::LEVEL[.='BEGIN']) - count($n/preceding-sibling::LEVEL[.='END'])"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <Data>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]"/>
        </Data>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="LEVEL[.='BEGIN']">
        <LEVEL>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
        </LEVEL>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[f:depth(.) = f:depth(current())][1]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="LEVEL[.='END']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The general idea of "sibling recursion" is that you write a template rule to process a single element, and from there you decide how to process the next sibling element. In this case the challenge is that the BEGIN template has to continue processing after the matching END, and I have done this by writing a function that computes the depth of each element as the difference between the number of preceding BEGINs and preceding ENDs.

In XSLT 1.0 I think you could do the same thing simply by expanding this `f:depth` function inline.

It would probably be more efficient to compute the depths of all elements in a single pass, and attach the value as an attribute to each element. Or in XSLT 3.0 the depth could be computed using a memo function, or an accumulator, or `xsl:iterate`. It could also perhaps be done using xsl:number.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not restricted to XSLT 1 then I would suggest a two step transformation, in XSLT 3 you could use an accumulator to ensure your LEVEL elements are decorated with a nesting level value in a first transformation step and then in a second step it becomes a straight-forward recursive `xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with/group-ending-with` grouping problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="level"/>

  <xsl:mode name="add-levels" on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="level"/>

  <xsl:accumulator name="level" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="LEVEL[. = 'BEGIN']" phase="start" select="$value + 1"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="LEVEL[. = 'END']" phase="end" select="$value - 1"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:template match="LEVEL" mode="add-levels">
      <LEVEL level="{accumulator-before('level')}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()" mode="#current"/>
      </LEVEL>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="indexed-levels">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="add-levels"/>
  </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:function name="mf:nest" as="node()*">
        <xsl:param name="nodes" as="node()*"/>
        <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$nodes" group-starting-with="LEVEL[. = 'BEGIN' and accumulator-before('level') = $level]">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="self::LEVEL[. = 'BEGIN' and accumulator-before('level') = $level]">
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-ending-with="LEVEL[. = 'END' and accumulator-before('level') = $level]">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="current-group()[last()][self::LEVEL[. = 'END' and accumulator-before('level') = $level]]">
                                <LEVEL>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="mf:nest(current-group()[position() lt last()], $level + 1)"/>
                                </LEVEL>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$indexed-levels/node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="mf:nest(*, 1)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZWp/8

Given the nature of accumulators, it would even suffice to use only one grouping step using directly the accumulator value instead of first inserting it into a temporary tree:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="level"/>

    <xsl:accumulator name="level" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="LEVEL[. = 'BEGIN']" phase="start" select="$value + 1"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="LEVEL[. = 'END']" phase="end" select="$value - 1"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:template match="LEVEL" mode="add-levels">
        <LEVEL level="{accumulator-before('level')}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()" mode="#current"/>
        </LEVEL>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="mf:nest" as="node()*">
        <xsl:param name="nodes" as="node()*"/>
        <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$nodes" group-starting-with="LEVEL[. = 'BEGIN' and accumulator-before('level') = $level]">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="self::LEVEL[. = 'BEGIN' and accumulator-before('level') = $level]">
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-ending-with="LEVEL[. = 'END' and accumulator-before('level') = $level]">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="current-group()[last()][self::LEVEL[. = 'END' and accumulator-before('level') = $level]]">
                                <LEVEL>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="mf:nest(current-group()[position() lt last()], $level + 1)"/>
                                </LEVEL>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="mf:nest(*, 1)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZWp/7

Answer (score -1):

For the query,

> I cant just add start tag or end tag based on condition.

One of the way to do is as below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LEVEL">
    <xsl:if test=".='BEGIN'">
        <xsl:variable name="startTag">
            <xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="'level'" />
            <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$startTag" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test=".='END'">
        <xsl:variable name="endTag">
            <xsl:text>&lt;/</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="'level'" />
            <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$endTag" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQfA

Comment: @Jags Just be aware that this is a hack that (a) may produce an invalid XML result and (b) may not work on all processors (DOE support is optional).

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k for the suggestions. :) Yes, it may not work on all processors but as far as the input is valid, it won't harm. It won't create invalid output.

Comment: `disable-output-escaping` is a horrible hack and it is absolutely the wrong solution to this problem. Downvoting. It only works if your processor output is going straight to a serializer and that seriously impacts the reusability and maintainability of your code.

Comment: @MichaelKay : okay.. would you please elaborate in what context or what case it can affect the outcome? I’m just asking it for my knowledge.. Thanks.

Comment: You can find an example of the mess people get into with d-o-e at http://saxon-xslt-and-xquery-processor.13853.n7.nabble.com/xsl-copy-and-disable-output-escaping-td8020.html. Essentially the problem is that your code stops working if you try to use it in a slightly more complicated setting, e.g. if you need to apply further processing to the output. That's because it's only defined in terms of a fudge to the basic data model, where XSLT transforms a tree of input nodes to a tree of output nodes. d-o-e requires a "side-channel" of communication between the transformer and the serializer.

Comment: @MichaelKay:  Yes. I had slightly misinterpreted the use of `disable-output-escaping`. I assumed it implicitly considers the node as part of DOM tree. I have gone through the above examples. Thank you so much for your response.